# Java method returns an enum which implements an interface

Tags: java, generics

How can I specify that a Java method returns an enum which implements an interface?
This method is given:

```
public <T extends Enum<T> & SomeInterface> void someMethod(Class<T> type) {
}
```

And I want to do:

```
someMethod(anotherMethod());
```

What should be the signature of `anotherMethod`?

Comment: It needs to return a Class of an enum type which meets your requirements.

Comment: So you want to write a method `anotherMethod` which returns an instance of `Class<T>` ?

Answer (score 3):

If `someMethod` expects a `Class<T>` parameter, where `T extends Enum<T> & SomeInterface`, then that's what you need to return from `anotherMethod`. And since you don't have anything in the parenthesis in your desired call, I would say simply:

`public Class<T extends Enum<T> & SomeInterface> anotherMethod()`

Comment: It wasn't there when I started typing that. :p

Comment: This will not compile `T extends Enum<T>` here is not same as what is expected.

Comment: `Class<T extends Enum<T> & SomeInterface> ` not a valid return type

Answer (score 3):

Correct Implementation should be

```
<T extends Enum<? extends T> & SomeInterface> void someMethod(Class<T> type);

<T extends Enum<? extends T> & SomeInterface>  Class<T>  anotherMethod();
```

Please check [More Fun with Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html)

Or More Simpler Version

```
public class Example<T extends Enum<T> & SomeInterface> {
  public void someMethod(Class<T> type) {}
  public Class<T> anotherMethod() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`anotherMethod` just needs to return a `Class`, it could be the exact class you have in mind that extends your enum and interface, or just a wildcard `Class<?>` (though you'll have compile time warnings). If you want to avoid the warnings, the return type needs to be `Class<T>` with a generics definition of `T` as in the method you're calling.

Comment: It is in fact impossible for `T` **not** to extend `Enum<T>`, but still extend `Enum`. `T` is an `enum` and that's just the way enums are implemented.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. Simplifies the whole process I guess. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: When Java 5 first came out, our favorite pastime was letting unsuspecting colleagues stare at `Class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>` and try to suppress the symptoms of sea sickness :)

Comment: Perhaps I should add an enum or two to some of our more crazy generics definitions then... They're already pretty bad (example: `ExtendableJpaObject<TYPE, ID_TYPE extends Comparable<ID_TYPE>, EXT extends JpaExtensionObject<?, ?, ?>>
    extends JpaObject<TYPE, ID_TYPE>`) :P

Comment: For every experienced dev a time comes when he realizes that Java looked better with all those Object params and explicit downcasts :)

Comment: True, but you get around that by making complicated generics lists like that to make all the other code look cleaner, leave it in some base interface somewhere, and never look at it again.